# Facebook php sdk problom: Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

Graph returned an error: Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request

I don't know how to fix it

login.php

```
<?
session_start();
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '$id', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
'app_secret' => '$secret',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2', 
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost:80/fb_test/fb-
callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!
</a>';
 ?>
```

fb-callback.php

```
 <?
session_start();

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => '1428245583931211', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
'app_secret' => 'cf045e5b4da0abf920b01447f23b09cd',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
// When Graph returns an error
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
if ($helper->getError()) {
header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
} else {
header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
echo 'Bad request';
}
exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId('{app-id}'); // Replace {app-id} with 
your app id
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it 
here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
// Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
try {
$accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
} catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . 
"</p>\n\n";
exit;
}

echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
//header('Location: http:/localhost:80/fb_test/');
?>
```

this is my app settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8smqN.jpg)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

The `getAccessToken` method generates the redirect URI parameter for the API call to exchange the code for a token based on the current URL, if none is passed explicitly.

So if you are not handling the triggering of login (meaning, the call to `getLoginUrl`) and processing the returned code value in the same script under the same URL, then you have to pass the first URL to `getAccessToken` explicitly, so that it sets the same value when making the API request, as `getLoginUrl` specified when the whole process was started.

```
try {$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken('http(s)://whatever/path/login.php');
```